# Sharepoint hosted app to replace search center

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, sharepoint-hosted-app, sharepoint-addin

So I've finally got the search CSOM to give me results back in my sharepoint hosted add-in/app. I can install/deploy it out, I can even add it to our catalog. I can then add the app in the site contents page - but that seems to be also how I launch and run it.

What I want to do is take the default search center page and replace it with my sharepoint add-in/app. Is this possible?  I just want to be able to click "edit page" and see my app available as a web part or something.

But it seems the app/add-in can only just be run by click it's time under site contents.

How can I use my app, not "on" my existing page, but AS my page??

Answer (score 1):

You can add `app-part or client webpart` in your app for this. That way it will be accessible as a webpart when you edit the page and try to add it. Find more details [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524232/StepplusbyplusStepplusguideplustopluscreateplusapl)

Comment: Thanks for your response - i've seen that page you linked and every time I try to follow the steps I just don't see my app listed in either the app parts or web parts when I do edit page -> insert.  There must be some steps that aren't explained that I am missing.

Comment: Ok I take back my comment...partially. I can get my app part listed on my Developer site - but not on any other sites/site collections/pages that I am really wanting it to be on.

Comment: The app part will only be visible on the site where app is deployed. I am not sure but you might want to try deploying it at tenant level and check if it is available then. for tenant level deployment check below link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179896.aspx#Web

Comment: you will need admin rights for this.